# Java applet downloading & launching exe; exe is unable to show pop up

Tags: c#, java, applet

I'm using Java applet to successfully download and launch C# application.
C# application on some cases try to install X509 certificate.

This should trigger a prompt from system that "You are about to install a certificate..." with "Yes" or "No" buttons (focus is set on No).

I don't see this pop up when launched from an applet. It seems someone dismissed it with "No".
In fact even a "Hello world" message box doesn't show up.

It works fine if I just double click an application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I would imagine that this would all depend greatly on the security settings of the browser. Running OS Native executable code is a sticky situation.

Comment: Same behavior across all browsers.

Comment: Is the applet digitally signed by you, and trusted by the end user?

Answer (score 0):

You might try to request full trust from the C# executable, but I don't think it will be possible to call it from a Java applet.

[Granting FullTrust to an assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970588/granting-fulltrust-to-an-assembly)

Instead, you may verify the certificate when you establish a connection without installing it using either C# or Java. You must compare the hash of the server certificate with a value retrieved from the application settings or from an hard-coded constant.

In C#, you may add a callback object with the validation code using this code to register the callback.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
    OnServerCertificateValidationCallback;
```

And this code as the callback method.

```
private static bool OnServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, 
    X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
{
  return certificate.GetCertHashString()
      .Equals(certificateHash, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

In Java, I cannot disclose the code I used but it was inspired by the **EasySSLSocketFactory** and **EasyX509TrustManager** classes found in this repository. It is Android code, but I don't think it depends on any Android specific features.

http://code.google.com/p/exchangeit/source/browse/trunk/src/com/byarger/exchangeit/

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I'd have to install certificate. Which will be used for Non Http communication. Also my C# app is signed by developer license. I think I'll try out CasPol.exe and see if earn the trust!

Comment: Solved my particular problem by generating certificate using Bouncy Castle instead of using .pfx file.Thus avoiding a prompt...